# Trying to make sense of Python/Jupyter environment on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, macos-catalina

Background:  while running Jupyter Notebook a new import was failing even though the library was installing successfully using pip3.  Some of the set up for the code I was running was done in PyCharm which was using a virtual Python 3.8.2 environment.  The failing import library is in the virtual environment so why isn't Jupyter seeing it?

I went looking and found that there are multiple versions of Python installed:

- /Library/Python/2.7
- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
- /usr/local/bin/python3
- /usr/local/bin/python3.8
- /usr/local/bin/jupyter (included this in case it clarifies things)
- /usr/bin/python
- /usr/bin/python3
- /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1
- /Users/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 (anaconda was uninstalled months ago so why is this still  here?)
- /Users/xxx/git/moat-ds/venv/lib/python3.8

I have installed pyenv and virtualenv and tried (unsuccessfully) to sort things out through [this](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#virtual-environments-and-pyenv) and [similar](https://amaral.northwestern.edu/resources/guides/pyenv-tutorial) articles.  But all of this has only left me with questions:

- what are these different directories doing?
- when launched what is Jupyter notebook using for 'python 3' kernel?
- where are the python packages stored when I run pip3 at the CLI (in pycharm packages are put in the \venv folder but otherwise?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying @Akbar30bill's answer without success I did `brew doctor` and restarted my terminal and tried again and it worked. Wasn't linked correctly or something.

Answer (score 2):

installing jupyter with pip from pyenv fixed my problem

```sh
brew uninstall jupyter
pip install jupyter
```

and after restarting your console it should be pyenv's jupyter

Comment: I will try that but after I understand what is actually going on.  For example, what are 'LIbrary/Frameworks'?  Why do I seemingly have 3.8.2 installed but still have an Ananconda 3.7 present, why wasn't the latter deleted?  Does that mean every time I install python the versions just pile up?  It just seems a mess.

Comment: tried it but no change in behaviour.  Uninstalled everything and tried a reinstall only to get following error when I tried to launch Jupyter notebook: 'zsh: /usr/local/bin/jupyter: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: no such file or directory'  Came from NodeJS/Windows where everyone told me packaging was a headache ... clearly they hadn't tried Python/MacOS

Answer (score 0):

A few years later and here is how I now handle this situation:

1. install miniconda
2. for every python project create an environment using `conda create <env name> python=3.10.8` (or whatever version you want)

This means that every python project has exactly the python version I specify.  My workflow is basically:

1. create git repo
2. create env
3. open env
4. write a list of all packages in a `requirements.txt` file
5. pip install *all* packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

The last one is important.  I've *always* found my packages (data science) in `pip` but not always in `conda`, and mixing `conda` and `pip` packages has always led to tears.  This way I keep it all pure.

Note:  why `miniconda` and not `venv`?  Because that's what all the devs in our office are using, no other reason.